# Prettyphoto with long title description on <a> tag cause the script to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

I use PrettyPhoto on my website.

When I put a long `title` attribute, the script to fails:

```
<a href="http://2012.nickmicho.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/nimic24_manson_flatten-682x1024.jpg"  data-url="http://clients.guylabbe.ca/nickpresta/product.php?id_product=32"  title="Disponibility print:Archive paper 24&quot; X 36&quot; only 25 copy -signed &amp; numbered18&quot; X 24&quot; only 100 copy - signed &amp; numbered Metal plate8&quot; X 12&quot; illimitedThis piece of art who display the artist Marilyn Manson. To ensure the quality and the durability of this art piece, the illustration is printed out of a top of line printer on matte paper. This will allow the illustration to last decade if enclosed in a good frame. Made in 2010." rel="pp[gal]"><img src="http://2012.nickmicho.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/nimic24_manson_flatten-206x310.jpg" alt="Marilyn Manson Interpretation" /></a>
```

any idea?

Comment: Can you please provide with working example of this error? http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.com

Comment: Live example of this error : http://goo.gl/SRWAz (click the first image down in the list).. the creator of the plugin told me Title is too long but there must be a solution?

Comment: I had to remove the access to the live example ... but if you keep in mind that the bug is about the Title being too long, what may I do?

Comment: Please provide full links and not shorted. Sorry for my arrogant approach.

Comment: no prob!here is the link : http://2012.nickmicho.com/expositions/headbangers-babes-blood-2010 ... but strange thing, I removed the Title attribute and now I get a Msie error in javascript console...

Comment: Found the solution... This is not about a too-long-array, this is a problem with a loop in pP that is resizing the lightbox. The long description makes the box too high and the loop never ends. So browser crashes. Solution : around line 630 ... where self function _fitToViewport is called within it